# Cypress run command not running during Jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cypress, yarnpkg

I am in the process of running an integration in Jenkins. The gist of the problem is as follows:

I have cloned a git of the application I am to working on into my workstation, then created a directory, initialised it in git and yarn, then installed cypress in it.

I then entered the following lines in the pertinent Jenkinsfile:

```
yarn install
.
.
.
cd (testing-directory)
yarn run cypress run --browser chrome --headless
```

At this point, the build fails.

The error message I get is:

error Command "cypress" is not found.

However, the command `yarn run cypress run --browser chrome --headless` runs perfectly on the cypress installation in the instance of this git in my local machine.

Please advise how I can have this command run during the Jenkins build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem. I needed to have Jenkins install Cypress in the build.

Hence I added the line:

```
yarn add cypress --dev -W
```

It worked and I am on my way again!

Update: I had (inadvertently) initialised this subfolder as a main package, so it was performing independently of the rest of the folder structure. I deleted the .git folder within and all issues have been solved without having to install cypress all over again.